# What is wrong with this async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So far my experience with async functions has gone pretty well until the moment I need to actually wait for a task to finish. This code sometimes pings the server, depending if it gets there before the application exits:

```
async void Main(string[] args)
{
    await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://localserver");
}
```

This code hangs indefinitely and never pings the server:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://localserver").Wait();
}
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: No repro. In my PC your code (with `Wait`) throws an `HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (localserver:80)` after a few seconds (wrapped in an `AggregateException`).

Answer (score 4):

Never `.Wait()` an awaitable; always `await`.

There's a ***little*** wriggle room re the superlatives in there, but the scenarios where it matters are niche and don't apply to most code.

A `void` method with an `await` is unpredictable precisely because the caller can't determine the execution's status; basically: never (same caveat) use `async void`: use `async Task`, and make sure the caller awaits it.

As for why it blocked: probably a deadlock due to a sync-context on a UI. If none of those words make sense: don't worry, they don't need to if you just use `await` instead of `.Wait()`

(For clarity: everything said about `.Wait()` also applies to `.Result`, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, or anything else you can cite)

Comment: so how to i wait for it to finish? ive never seen anything mentioned but Wait'

Comment: "never ... use `async void`". An `async` main method should return a `Task`.

Comment: @PetNoire then whatever guide you're reading: is very very wrong; `.Wait()` undoes *everything that async tries to achieve* - and introduces a deadlock risk in some scenarios, as an added kick in the pants; as for how to wait for it to finish: that is *exactly what `await` does* (but: rather than blocking the current thread, it uses an async callback pattern when needed)

Comment: i need it to block though.
and the void task isnt part of the issue. if HttpClient.GetAsync().Wait() is literally the only line in the entire code, it hangs and i cant find anything else that will let me wait for it to complete

Comment: @PetNoire what makes you think you have to block, instead of using async/await? Note that HttpClient has regained some sync methods in recent updates, but async is still preferred

Comment: what i have going on is a splash screen comes up and a background thread uses a stopwatch to test a few server connections to see which one is fastest. i need to make sure all the tests have finished and the best link gets set before the app continues

Comment: @PetNoire and what makes you think you can't use async there; async and UI works fine, as long as you don't call Wait()